# Converting cURL Facebook API POSTs into R and storing the result

Tags: r, facebook-graph-api, curl, rcurl, httr

There are variations on this in existing posts, but specifically for the Facebook API I'd like to be able to use cURL to POST photos to the API using R and store the returned ID.

An example would be:

```
curl -i -X POST \
-d "url=https://wheremyimageishosted.com/test_photo.png" \
-d 'published=false' \
-d "access_token=<my_access_token>" \
"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/me/photos"
```

And what is returned is in the format of:

```
{"id":"1234123412341234"} .
```

I know there are various packages for cURL for R, but they're not the easiest to understand for an R intermediate, but cURL beginner.

Thus, the two asks here are:

1. What would the above cURL code be using something like httr or RCurl (and the best package to use)?
2. How can I store the numeric value returned as a variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why someone would downvote me, but to answer my own question, I'd recommend the wonderful httr package for converting cURL into R. I've got it to work for a number calls to and from the Facebook API.  The last stumbling block for me was to remember to use

```
encode = "json"
```

... where appropriate.  Details are here:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html

Comment: Update - I wrote a package FBinsightsR just to handle the import of ad insights. It's on GitHub: https://github.com/Deducive/FBinsightsR